# Check Gmail for Responses from specific emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to build a script that will look through gmail and tell me if a someone has responded to me. So anytime a have an email `from` someone within a thread, it populates the sheet.

```
Sheet 1:
| Email Address | Responded? |
| harry@hey.com |   YES      |
| barry@hey.com |   NO       |
| saun@wia.com  |   YES      |
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: show us attempts and specific coding issues so we can help. So far we've only seen a specification.

Comment: my thoughts would be to check [Gmail Service Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/#methods) and show us what you've tried.